# Custom component inside dynamic component not initializing

Tags: javascript, angular

I am adding the `TestComponent` component dynamically:

```
public loadComponent() {
    const componentFactory =
        this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TestComponent);
    const viewContainerRef = this.customModalElement.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent < any > (componentFactory);
}
```

Inside `TestComponent` I render custom component:

```
<h1>Test Component</h1>
<app-custom-component></app-custom-component>
```

The problem is the `app-custom-component` does not render (not initializing). On screen I can see only `h1` tag.

What I have to do to render nested custom component? Doesn't it render/initialize automatically, when the `TestComponent` is rendered?

The curious thing is when i first initialize app-custom-component (by going to route where this component is rendered) - it works. But without initialization it does not worki.

Comment: Are you getting errors saying that `app-custom-component` is not registered in the module? What version of Angular? Using Ivy?

Comment: i'm not getting any error and i don't use Ivy.